# Ruby custom shuffle method

Tags: ruby, shuffle

So I have this code which is supposed to resemble the Fisher-Yates shuffling in Ruby but I can't figure the multiple assignment on line 5. Can someone clarify what exactly is happening here?

```
def shuffling(arr = [])
  length = arr.length
  arr.each_with_index do |element, index|
    i = rand(length)
    arr[index], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[index]
  end
  arr
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: just remember `each` return same array, `map` return modified array.

Comment: You treat it the same way as if it was splited into separated rows:`arr[index] = arr[i]` and on the next row - `arr[i] = arr[index]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're flip flopping a random index with the current index.

So if you have an array of `[2,4,5]`

the first time through `index` is 0 (which is element 2).  Say `i` = 1.

That assignment now makes `index` of 1 equal to the `value` of index at 0, then there is another assignment of `index` of 0 equal to the `value` of index at 1.

So the array becomes `[4,2,5]`

Comment: he can avoid this by pass index `arr.each.with_index(1)` now index start from `1`.